# Writing sheets generator

Tags: handwriting, websites, fonts

When I was in China I bought some writing books for practicing Chinese handwriting. This is good but have 2 disadvantages.

1. Size of cell is too small for brush and too big for roller pen. Must
   be for some fat marker.
2. Characters themselves are not the ones I am learning and interested in.

So my solution is — Web service — Chinese Characters sheets generator.

- You choose your favorite font (some nice classics).
- Select size - roller, marker, brush.
- Type in characters to learn.
- Press 'process' - you get PDF page with cells and first cell has
  your character with pinyin.

My question is: are there any such tools so I do not have to reinvent bicycle?

Comment: Some free websites for generating worksheets are:
http://www.chineseworksheetgenerator.org/
https://www.chinesetools.eu/tools/chinese-grid/  Some other websites such as HanziGrid are good but not completely free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One such website is: http://www.hanzigrids.com

Another website is http://cop.yes-chinese.com/hanban/tzg/ but it has less features and you can't choose your font.

Comment: 这正是我需要的. Sorry still can't upvote.

Comment: @Whity: Now you should be able to vote :-)

Comment: Got 100 points last night. Now I can.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of grids available [Hanzi Practice Sheets II](http://cml.chinesemandarin.org/2012/06/hanzi-practice-sheets-ii-hanzi-grids.html) and a free customizable  one here [Hanzi Practice Sheets](http://cml.chinesemandarin.org/2011/07/hanzi-practice-sheets.html). There is also Arch Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Another one is http://www.chine-culture.com/en/chinese/chinese-writing-grids-generator.php

If you learn Chinese you will like there's pinyin on my grids :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxzdhaze85qaq8w/liens%20de%20t%C3%A9l%C3%A9chargement%20grille%20%C3%A9criture.docx?dl=0

follow that link to get updates : 
https://www.facebook.com/saintj0seph